# "One-sided" Predictor Variable in Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression

Background Information:

I have 6 subjects; we'll call them A,B,C,D,E, and F.

Suppose they are asked to shoot basketballs from a free-throw line into a basket.  A success is 1 and a failure is 0.

They performed as follows:

A - 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1

B - 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

C - 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

D - 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

E - 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

F - 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0

Question:

Now suppose I wanted to test that all of these subjects had the same probability of making a basket.

I would set up the logistic regression as such: Success being the probability of scoring a basket, and subject being the predictor variable.

Success ~ Subject.

Now this is where I get tangled up; I have one sided predictor variables, and what I mean by that is there is a subject that scored all of their baskets, and a subject that scored none of their's.  How do we handle this type of logistic regression in r?  Or can you suggest another method?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: This isn't a programming question; this is a data modeling question. If you need help choosing statistical models, you should ask your question over at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm kind of in this grey area to where I could get the same response from both sites.  It's a logistic regression issue that I've never run into before.  It's theory related, but it's also a question of how I would correct whatever is going on in r; whether it is a transformation or something else.

Comment: Well, you first need to determine what you want to do. That's not a language specific question. You need to know what's right for your data first. If you get stuck on the "how" part of the question then that might belong here.